# OpenCV having problems closing windows

Tags: python, opencv

I am using OpenCV to read an image from a stream of a frame about every half a minute and showing it. The code is:

```
import cv2
import zmq
import base64
import numpy as np

context = zmq.Context()
footage_socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
footage_socket.bind('tcp://An IP')
footage_socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, np.unicode(''))

cv2.startWindowThread()
cv2.namedWindow("Stream")

while True:
    try:

        frame= footage_socket.recv_string()
        img= base64.b64decode(frame)
        npimg= np.fromstring(img, dtype=np.uint8)
        decoded= cv2.imdecode(npimg, 1) 
        cv2.imshow("Stream", decoded)      
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> seems to do nothing.
I tried adding:

```
if cv2.waitKey(1)& 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

But I get the error `Attempt to unlock mutex that was not locked Aborted` and my program doesn't run at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can restart the kernel and add the cv2.destroyAllWindows() when keyboardinteruppt triggers

```
while True:
try:

    frame= footage_socket.recv_string()
    img= base64.b64decode(frame)
    npimg= np.fromstring(img, dtype=np.uint8)
    decoded= cv2.imdecode(npimg, 1) 
    cv2.imshow("Stream", decoded)
    if cv2.waitKey(1)& 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break      
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    break
```

Comment: I made the modifications suggested, I still get: "Attempt to unlock mutex that was not locked Aborted (core dumped)"

Comment: This is needed, otherwise my stream show  window is marked as "not responding" by the OS due to the low image refresh rate, I couldn't solve this problem any other way.

Comment: these two lines are actually not necessary. cv2.startWindowThread()
cv2.namedWindow("Stream") try it without them and see if its still showing not responding

Comment: Ok, I tried it. Windows is still marked as not responding, also seems to update the view with images from the stream whenever it pleases.